# Node.JS fast-csv throws error while reading file

Tags: node.js, csv

I try to use fast-csv in Node.JS to open a csv file with below code.
The path is correct but when running the code, it will display the first hundreds of records at begining, but then it always breaks in a random place and throws below error:

**event.js:183
throw er://unhandled 'error' event

Error: ENOENT:  no such file or directory, read**

I'm very curious that my code is simple enough, the only file is the csv file quoted, there is no other file, since it has already successfully read several hundreds of records, which means the csv file obviously exists, so which file triggers this error? Why the error message does not give enough detail information which file is missing?

```
    var fastcsv=require("fast-csv");
    fastcsv
    .fromPath("cn_aoi_04232018_prod.csv",{headers:true})
    .on("data",function(data){
     console.log(data);
     )
    .on("end", function() {
     console.log("done"); 
     });
```

Comment: I tried to use a 2-records-only csv, it can successfully complete reading the 2 records but still throws the same error, and the "done" is never showed.